# Adding bootrap-react from NPM creates another package-lock file in Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-2019, react-bootstrap, package-lock.json

I am new to react and trying to add react-bootstrap to my project.

I've got a Soultion with multiple projects in Visual Studio.
As I've understand, I need to add a package for Bootstrap support.

Whenever I try to run:

`npm install --save react-bootstrap`

I am getting the following error in Package Manager Console:
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory , open 'C:\Dev\xxx\Projectname\package.json'

Another package-lock.json files is being added to the root of the solution.
Why does that happen? Shouldn't the dependency to react-bootstrap just populate the already existing package-lock.json inside the chosen project? What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by entering correct DIR before getting the package..

CD:

```
cd ./Project/ClientApp
```

Install:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap
```